# Tkinter very slow to initialize on Python 3.10.10

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 3 machines, all run Windows 10.

1. First has PyPy 7.3.9 (Python 3.9.10)
2. Second pure vanilla Python 3.9.1 downloaded from python.org and installed manually
3. Third has Python 3.10.10 installed via `winget`

I mostly develop on 1st PC and everything was fine, until I went to lab machines and noticed significant slowness. I reduced my code to the minimum:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
    
class STM_GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
start = time.time()
gui = STM_GUI()
took = time.time() - start
print("%.2f" % took)
gui.mainloop()
```

On PC#1 output: `0.06`.

on PC#2 output: `0.48`. (8 times longer, but ok)

on PC#3 output: `5.23`. (5 seconds to do nothing?!)

Question: why and how it can be mitigated?

Comment: Tried. Removed python from winget, installed by downloading from python.org. Result even worse - 5.58

Comment: For some additional context, I ran the snippet on 3.10.9 and got 0.16. Vanilla python downloaded and installed from python.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of digging turns out the issue was that home directory of lab machine user was mapped to quite remote network drive, which caused slowdown of `tkinter`.
Not sure, why it affected only `tkinter` and what exactly it was looking for there, but once the network drive was unmapped, performance got comparably high.
Wanted to delete the post, but decided to keep in case anyone hits similar issue.

Comment: If this is the problem then it has nothing to do with Tkinter and everything to do with trying to use a network drive; that's not something anyone else is particularly likely to run into, and it's a not a programming problem anyway.

Comment: It is something that I personally encountered working with Python and specifically with Tkinter. As you could guess from the snippet, remaining script parts were not affected. I spent several hours trying figure out and found the root cause only by lucky coincidence. Tkinter documentation does not mention that during init it searches for something at $HOME, so I had no clues what was the reason.